# Automatically round off - awk command

Tags: awk, rounding

I have a csv file and I want to add a column that takes some values from other columns and make some calculations. As a simplified version I'm trying this:

```
awk -F"," '{print $0, $1+1}' myFile.csv |head -1
```

The output is:

```
29.325172701023977,...other columns..., 30
```

The column added should be `30.325172701023977` but the output is rounded off.

I tried some options using printf, CONVFMT and OFMT but nothing worked.

How can I avoid the round off?

Comment: How about using `printf` in `awk` here?

Comment: Try something like: `awk -v var="29.325172701023977" 'BEGIN{printf("%2.15f\n",var+1)}'` to get expected output for sample value.

Comment: Which region of the world are you from ? See [the discussion here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/163304-awk-string-number-conversion.html) which could give you some clues.

Comment: When trying awk -v var="29.325172701023977" 'BEGIN{printf("%2.15f\n",var+1)}' I got 30,325172701023977; with a "," instead of a "."

Comment: I made it work this way: 
LC_NUMERIC=POSIX awk -F"," 'BEGIN{ OFMT="%.15f" }{print $0, $1+1}' myFile.csv |head -1
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the number of decimal places is not known beforehand
- the number of decimal places can vary from line to line

Setup:

```
$ cat myfile.csv
29.325172701023977,...other columns...
15.12345,...other columns...
120.666777888,...other columns...
46,...other columns...
```

One `awk` idea where we use the number of decimal places to dynamically generate the `printf "%.?f"` format:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
      { split($1,arr,".")                         # split $1 on period
        numdigits=length(arr[2])                  # count number of decimal places
        newNF=sprintf("%.*f",numdigits,$1+1)      # calculate $1+1 and format with "numdigits" decimal places
        print $0,newNF                            # print new line
      }
' myfile.csv
```

**NOTE:** assumes OP's locale uses a decimal/period to separate integer from fraction; for a locale that uses a comma to separate integer from fraction it gets more complicated since it will be impossible to distinguish between a comma as integer/fraction delimiter vs field delimiter without some changes to the file's format

This generates:

```
29.325172701023977,...other columns...,30.325172701023977
15.12345,...other columns...,16.12345
120.666777888,...other columns...,121.666777888
46,...other columns...,47
```

Answer (score 1):

as long as you aren't dealing with numbers greater than `9E15`, there's no need to fudge any one of `CONVFMT`, `OFMT`, or `s/printf()` at all :

> ```
> {m,g}awk '$++NF = int((_=$!__) + sub("^[^.]*",__,_))_' FS=',' OFS=','
> ```

```
29.325172701023977,...other columns...,30.325172701023977
15.12345,...other columns...,16.12345
120.666777888,...other columns...,121.666777888
46,...other columns…,47
```

if `mawk-1` is sending ur numbers to scientific notation do :

> ```
> mawk '$++NF=int((_=$!!NF)+sub("^[^.]*",__,_))_' FS=',' OFS=',' CONVFMT='%.f'
> ```

*when u scroll right you'll notice all input digits beyond the decimal point are fully preserved*

```
    2929292929.32323232325151515151727272727270707070701010101010232323232397979797977,...other columns...,2929292930.32323232325151515151727272727270707070701010101010232323232397979797977
    1515151515.121212121234343434345,...other columns...,1515151516.121212121234343434345
    12121212120.66666666666767676767777777777788888888888,...other columns...,12121212121.66666666666767676767777777777788888888888
    4646464646,...other columns…,4646464647

    2929.32325151727270701010232397977,...other columns...,2930.32325151727270701010232397977
    1515.121234345,...other columns...,1516.121234345
    12120.66666767777788888,...other columns...,12121.66666767777788888
    4646,...other columns...,4647
```

change it to `CONVFMT='%\47.f'`, and you can even get `mawk-1` to nicely comma format them for u :

```
29292929292929.323232323232325151515151515172727272727272707070707070701010101010101023232323232323979797979797977,...other columns…,29,292,929,292,930.323232323232325151515151515172727272727272707070707070701010101010101023232323232323979797979797977
    
15151515151515.12121212121212343434343434345,...other columns…,15,151,515,151,516.12121212121212343434343434345

121212121212120.666666666666666767676767676777777777777777888888888888888,…other columns…,121,212,121,212,121.666666666666666767676767676777777777777777888888888888888

46464646464646,...other columns...,46,464,646,464,647
```